# pandas.read_csv: Using converters AND other preprocessors together

Tags: python, pandas, csv, converters

When reading a csv file with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), it seems that when using the keyword `converters` some other preprocessing arguments (tested with `decimal` and `na_values`) seem to have no effect. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = "A B C\n12,5 4 xxx\n3,1 7 5,6\n8 n/a 7"
buffer = StringIO(txt)

converters = {i: lambda x: x for i in range(3)}  # dummy converter

df1 = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=" ", decimal=",", na_values=["xxx"])
buffer.seek(0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=" ", decimal=",", na_values=["xxx"], converters=converters)

print(df1)
print(df2)


      A    B    C
0  12.5  4.0  NaN
1   3.1  7.0  5.6
2   8.0  NaN  7.0
      A    B    C
0  12,5    4  xxx
1   3,1    7  5,6
2     8  n/a    7
```

`df1` is imported correctly, while `df2` holds unconverted strings (dtype: object). Obviously the arguments `decimal` and `na_values` are ignored as soon as a converter is defined explicitly for the column. Even the integrated default NA-conversion of the string `"n/a"` fails (`keep_default_na=True`)

**Question:** Is there a way to use `converters` *and* other preprocessing arguments together? Or do I have to extend my application specific converters with additional decimal sign and NA-value converters manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. Even if the documentation is not clear about `sep`, `decimal` and `thousands` parameters except for `dtype`:

> If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

Consider this parameters as only used by the default converter of `read_csv`.

A possible solution is to let `read_csv` parse your file then use `assign` to modify the value of each column.

For instance:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=';', decimal=',', thousands='_')
        .assign(col1=lambda x: converters(x['col1']),
                col2=lambda x: converters(x['col2']))
```

Comment: I figured out in your example `converters` would be the converter-function, not a dict of converter-functions. Seems like a good workaround.

Comment: Yes you are right. I meant something like `col1=lambda x: converters['col1'](x['col1'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look into detail why it is so, but it looks like this depends on engine used. You can specify `engine='python'` in order for it to work

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = "A B C\n12,5 4 xxx\n3,1 7 5,6\n8 4 7"
buffer = StringIO(txt)

converters = {i: lambda x: x for i in range(3)}  # dummy converter

df1 = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=" ", decimal=",", na_values=["xxx"])
buffer.seek(0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=" ", decimal=",", na_values=["xxx"], converters=converters, engine='python')

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

output:

```
      A  B    C
0  12.5  4  NaN
1   3.1  7  5.6
2   8.0  4  7.0
      A  B    C
0  12.5  4  NaN
1   3.1  7  5.6
2     8  4    7
```

Comment: `df2.dtypes` suggests it did only work partly, all types are `object`

Comment: use `converters = {0:float, 1:int, 2:float}`, still c column will be `object`. i.e. it's not due to using `converters` option per se. On other hand if you dtype, instead of converters....